# What becomes the start date when a Residence Permit is extended?

Tags: working-visas, resident-permit, netherlands

I have 6 months until the expiry of my Netherlands Residence Permit (RP) on 31st December. This allows me to start the process of having an extension for another 2 years.

If I begin the process now, will the start date of my new RP be the date it is issued, or would it begin on 1st January, moving it forward two years from when the current one expires?

I did try to get this information online, but in vain.

Comment: It should start from the date it is issued.

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat older information (2013), but on [this Dutch forum page](https://www.buitenlandsepartner.nl/archive/index.php/t-50380-p-2.html) several people report that their new 'Verblijfsvergunning Regulier' permit starts on the end date of the current one.

This is how prolongation of licenses/permits usually works in The Netherlands.<sup>*</sup>

<sup>* Dutch people would never tolerate 'losing' days if the start date of the prolongation is before the end date of the previous period ;-)</sup>